# Create a "counter" on matlab from 0:limit-1. The length of counter is not determined in the program

Tags: python, matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

Q- Create a "counter" from 0:limit-1 (for example if you choose 3 it will display 0,1,2). The length of counter is not determined in the program and it should be determined when it is being run and the inputs can differ from each other

this is the solution on python but i want to compute it on matlab. how do i do that?

```
for i in range(3):
    print(3-i)
for s in range(3,-1,-1)
    print s
```

so the answer is :

```
3
2
1
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html Use the colon operator, see the first example in that link. This is one of the fundamental syntax elements of Matlab.

Comment: so youre saying that i should use the first example for my question?

Comment: what about the "print" command?

Comment: you don't need a print command in matlab, you can just leave off the ; at the end and it will print the result of that line to the command line. If you want to be a bit neater you can look at `disp` or also `sprintf`

Comment: can you please help me with the solution?

Comment: This is literally the most basic Matlab question you could possibly be asking. Do some tutorials. The solution is `0:(limit-1)`, that is literally the solution.

Answer (score 2):

As Dan hinted you in the comments above, [the colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) of Matlab already do what you want.

Here are examples corresponding to your Python example:

Using the bare colon operator:

```
3:-1:0
```

gives

```
ans =
     3     2     1     0
```

which is a 1 by 4 row vector.

You'll get the same result with:

```
limit = 3;
limit:-1:0
```

---

If you want to use this as a basis for a loop:

```
limit = 3;
for i = limit:-1:0
    disp(i)
end
```

will output:

```
 3
 2
 1
 0
```

---

More generally you could do:

```
istart = 6;
istep = -2;
iend = 0;

for i = istart:istep:iend
    disp(i)
end
```

which gives:

```
 6
 4
 2
 0
```